# Coupling of a size biased reordered sequence

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, coupling

Given a finite sequence of positive real numbers $\mathbf w = (w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)$, the size biased reordering of $\mathbf w$ is a random vector ${\mathbf w}_o = (w_{r(1)},w_{r(2)},\ldots,w_{r(n)})$ defined by

\begin{equation}
\mathbb P(w_{r(1)} = w_j) = \frac{w_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P(w_{r(k)} = w_j\vert w_{r(1)},w_{r(2)},\ldots,w_{r(k-1)}) = \frac{w_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}w_{r(i)}}.
\end{equation}

My question is the following: Is there an explicit coupling of $w_{r(1)}$ and $w_{r(k)}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb P(w_{r(1)}\geq w_{r(k)}) = 1,
\end{equation}
for a fixed $k$? In other words, is it true that $w_{r(1)}$ stochastically dominates $w_{r(k)}$ for any $k>1$?

edit: the question above is now obsolete.

A follow-up question is: Is it true that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb E[w_{r(1)}] \geq \mathbb E[w_{r(k)}],
\end{equation}
for any fixed $k>1$?

Comment: "Intuitively it seems very clear" that this is *not* the case since $w_{r(1)}=\min\limits_kw_k$ with positive probability, and when this happens, what could possibly be $w_{r(k)}$? (Please add the hypothesis that every $w_k$ is positive, otherwise the question collapses.)

Comment: @Did Thank you. I have edited the question accordingly. I have now added a weaker question.

Comment: Please indicate clearly in the question that a part of it is now obsolete.

Comment: @Did Done, thanks!